# Monitoring performance metrics from Xen (xend) with Java

Tags: java, xen, performance-monitoring, bindings, metrics

I need to write a Java application that is collecting and monitoring (remotely and local) performance informations and metrics from a Xen hypervisor. This Java application should fetch the same informations from xen that „xm info“ and „xm top“ displays.

Used Xen version: Xen 4.1.3 with the deamon xend, the default toolstack and the console xm.

Questions:

- Can anyone tell me which direction I should look for a solution?
- Is there a Java binding respectively a Java API for Xen (with xend
  and the default toolstack with xm)?
- I understood it using Libvirt (that has a Java binding) requires to
  use the toolstack Libvirt in Xen. So, is it possible to have both
  installed, the default toolstack and Libvirt?
- Or are the performance informations available via XML-RPC when using
  xend (without Libvirt or XAPI)?

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is slightly off topic, as it centers more on developing such an application. If you are satisfied with just using one, then consider this:

My application of choice for collecting performance data on hosts is [*collectd*](http://collectd.org).

There is a pure Java port of collectd called [jcollectd](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Jcollectd), see its [homepage](http://support.hyperic.com/display/hypcomm/jcollectd).

Collectd ships with a `libvirt` plugin, which should be able to collect all information about hypervisor and VMs that you desire.
With the `network` plugin, you can send data from one collectd server to another.